# Support for AMD modules for Brunch

Tags: brunch

Our code is currently using dojo 1.5.4 and we will soon be moving to dojo 1.11 which is AMD. We are in the process of changing our build tool from componentjs since its deprecated now. I want to know if Brunch supports code/modules written in AMD format.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, check the docs here: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#modules

```
modules:
  wrapper: 'amd'
  definition: 'amd'
```